# Select count(*) doesn't return rows which have the results of 0 in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, count

Here is the sample table:

```
A      |     Column1      |      Column2
1               5                    8
1               3                    2
2               6                    9
2               2                    5
3               1                    3
```

Here is my query:

```
Select A,count(*) as C from myTable where Column1 > 3 group by A
```

The result should be:

```
A     |     C
1           1
2           1
3           0
```

But it gave me this result which excluded all 0 rows:

```
A     |     C
1           1
2           1
```

I want to include the rows which don't meet the condition in where clause.

Could I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause causes the `A = 3` not on the list because it filter the rows before the aggregation of the records.

```
SELECT  A,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Column1 > 3 THEN 1 END) TotalCount
FROM    myTable
GROUP   BY A
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/854c5/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══╦════════════╗
║ A ║ TotalCount ║
╠═══╬════════════╣
║ 1 ║          1 ║
║ 2 ║          1 ║
║ 3 ║          0 ║
╚═══╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause eliminates them. Try something like:

```
Select A,count(case when Column1 > 3 then 1 else null end) as C from myTable group by A
```